# Is my system 64-bit?

Tags: linux

```
uname -m
```

Gives me

```
x86_64
```

,but

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

gives

```
32
```

So my system is 64 or 32 bit?
(it's Gentoo and I don't have root access)

Comment: What does a `file` on `which getconf` give you? What does `/usr/libexec/conf/default` link to?

Comment: What did you install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU is 64-bit. Your kernel is 64-bit. Something else is 32-bit, but it's hard to tell what. Perhaps the `getconf` that comes first in your path is 32-bit. Look in `/usr/libexec/getconf` for clues.

**Update**: It sounds like you have a primarily 32-bit user space. Maybe someone just installed a 64-bit OS to get support for more than 4GB of physical memory. Maybe you have some 64-bit executables. But it's now obvious you have a mixed environment.

Comment: I don't have _/usr/libexec/_ :(

Comment: Okay. I wonder how your platform decides which configuration to target then.

Comment: from /usr/lib ? I'm not using BSD...

Comment: Fedora/Redhat use `/usr/libexec`. I guess Gentoo uses `/etc/make.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `arch` if it prints x86_64 you have 64bit. You get 32 for LONG_BIT because some applications you use are 32bit, could be in your case a gcc compiled as 32bit.

So your Arch is really 64bit and you can run 64bit applications but you have installed a 32bit gcc.

Comment: Arch gives me "x86_64". How to check if my gcc is 32-bit? I found out only, that my PHP is 32-bit.

Comment: `file $(which gcc)` run this in a terminal. If it prints something like this: `/usr/bin/gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped` you have a 64bit gcc. Otherwise it's probably 32bit take a look what is written behind ELF.

Comment: "/usr/bin/gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386"
So 32-bit.

Comment: There you got it. Something in your gentoobox is really missconfigured. And many applications just use `gcc` to compile even if you have x86_86-pc-linux-gnu-gcc. Somemore information about your Gentoo System would be useful. You're running a 64bit Kernel but have installed 32bit applications. So someone did change the CHOST or your kernel wasn't build on the system with the current installed 32bit gcc. Or it was installed there but cross-compiled.
@DavidSchwartz Yes, but it's really uncommon with Gentoo.

Comment: 64-bit kernel and 32-bit user space is not necessarily a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I cant remember if you need root access to be able to read the make.conf on Gentoo but try

```
grep CHOST /etc/make.conf
```

If you get

```
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
```

Then your system is set up to compile and install 64 bit packages. Otherwise if you get

```
CHOST="i686-pc-linux-gnu"
```

Then your system is set up for 32 bit.

If you don't get either then you may need root privileges.  Given your `uname` though I would expect your system to be 64-bit.

Comment: I got
CHOST="i686-pc-linux-gnu"
so why arch, uname -m and uname -r show it is 64 bit?

Comment: Okay, so you have a 64-bit CPU, 64-bit kernel, and 32-bit development environment and target platform. It's possible someone just installed a 64-bit kernel on a 32-bit userspace, maybe to get support for more than 4GB of physical memory. Maybe to allow 64-bit executables to work.

Comment: @Marqin I strongly suspect that David is right there, your system is set up for 32-bit, but someone has installed a 64-bit kernel.  Presumably so that all the memory is available to the OS, but will also ensure that there are no 64-bit compatibility problems (which are pretty rare anyway).